# Redirect between different pages in Blazor using javascript?

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

Is it possible to redirect/change pages in blazor using javascript. Is there something that can mimic blazor's NavigationManager in javascript ?

I tried using pushState, it does seem to change the URL in the browser tab but there is no change in the view.

At the moment, the only solution that I see is to use

```
window.location.href = "/blazor_app/view1";
```

but I would like to achieve this without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in way but you can always use JSInterop to achieve this.

For example in your .razor file that resembles the page you can inject the NavigationManager and the IJSRuntime:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IJSRuntime Js
```

Then in the @code{} section of your page .razor you can pass the NavigationManager to JS:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("receiveNavigationManager", DotNetObjectReference.Create(NavigationManager));
}
```

Then in JS you can use the received NavigationManager:

```
window.myNavigationManager.invokeMethodAsync("NavigateTo", "/myPagePath");

function receiveNavigationManager(navigationManager) {
    window.myNavigationManager = navigationManager;
}
```